# Converting a String to a Date with Date Format YYYYMM

Tags: date

I kind of stuck on this one. Basically, we have a string that is actually a date with a format YYYYMM. For example, 201901.

I wanted to convert this into a date record, but I found out that we could not set a particular date format in the method 'format()'.

Is there any way I could create a date record with date format YYYYMM?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the method newInstance to achieve this.

```
Date myDate = date.newinstance(1960, 2, 17); //YYYY, MM, DD
```

Just split the string (You can use `substring(startIndex, endIndex)` ) and pass in the method. For the day you may need to pass a static value(like 1).

Comment: Oh yeah. Now I understand. Thanks for the suggestion of having the date as just a static value. I actually forgot about that one, that's why I didn't use newinstance. Yes, I think this would work for me.

Comment: @JerardDelaVictoria If this solves your problem then you can accept the answer and close this question.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. yup. I coded this and it works! Thanks for the help.